# WMIC returnvalue = 3?

Tags: windows-server-2012, wmic

Am trying to install a simple msi from our DC to my machine for testing purposes, but, I keep on getting this one error:

```
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 3;
};
```

My syntax is:

```
/node:192.168.169.98 product call install true,"","C:\Users\administrator.domain\Desktop\2.msi"
```

Any thoughts?

Nothing online gave me a meaning for return value 3, and, I'm logged in as the domain admin on that DC and the command prompt is run in admin mode.

The target machine is Windows 10 and the source is Server 2012 R2.

Both are on our domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us the full command ?  "/node:" is not a valid command.

Comment: That is the command I use. I wouldn't be getting that error if it weren't a valid command.